# Is there a Qt C++ data container to use in dynamic size structs?

Tags: c++, qt, struct, sizeof

I thought this problem should be identified and solved by the community but it seems either I'm searching with the wrong keywords or it's really that elusive.

The problem is simple. I want to define a struct in which a dynamic data container (Vector, List, Queue, whatever works) should be defined.

```
 #pragma pack(1)

 struct Example
 {
    int foo;

    QVector<int> bar;
 };
```

I need to insert integer values to this Vector (or take any other Qt/STL container) and I want to copy this struct's contents to a byte array in order to write its raw data to a file.

What I encounter is that when I write the following code:

```
Example exstr;
qDebug()<<sizeof(exstr);
exstr.bar.push_back(12);
exstr.bar.push_back(5);
qDebug()<<sizeof(exstr);
```

It displays the values:

```
8
8
```

Now, this is probably because QVector is just an ordinary pointer which points to the contiguous data but what I need is a dynamically resizeable data container (which would also resize the struct it's in) and allow me to use the contents byte by byte when I try to serialize it.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your going to need to use a serialization library or roll your own if you want to output a container that is dynamically sized.

Comment: Do you want to know how many bytes in the vector?Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @CroCo That would help my cause but not completely solve the problem, because I would still have the serialization issue.
But generally, I would be very glad if someone suggested a way where I can see an increase in "sizeof" every time I insert a new element in a container.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715423/calculate-serialization-size-of-objects-in-qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **QDataStream** allows you to serialize some of the Qt data types: [Serializing Qt Data Types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html)

```
QDataStream stream(&file);   // we will serialize the data into the file
stream << your_qvector_obj;
//...
QVector<int> new_vec;
stream >> new_vec;
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code, I decided to wrap this idea in a class and handle the serialization jobs with this class' methods. That would do the trick I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with QVector. The STL vector class will also work. Both of these classes are guaranteed to store their values in contiguous memory.

For QVector, you need something like this:

```
memcpy (dest, bar.data(), bar.count () * sizeof (int));
```

For an STL vector, you take the address of the first element:

```
memcpy (dest, &bar[0], bar.size () * sizeof (int));
```

In both cases, "dest" must be large enough to hold the data you're copying. I'm using copying here as an example; if you just need a pointer to the data then QVector::data provides that, for an STL vector, the address of the first element provides it.